# vue create&append DOM элемент пример js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Начала изучать vue  пару дней назад. Разобралась с тем, как отрисовывать компоненты, но так и не поняла, как добавлять по событию элемент в dom. Конкретно, вопрос состоит в том, могу ли я в vue создать аналогично javascript dom-элемент по нажатию кнопки, а не так: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmLfjng4/6/)?

html:

```
<div id="app">
<input type="text" id="inp">
<button id="bt" >
send
</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
let app=document.querySelector('#app');
let bt=document.querySelector('#bt');
let inp=document.querySelector('#inp');
bt.addEventListener('click',function(){
    let p=document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML= inp.value;
    app.appendChild(p);
});
```

[ссылка на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/697233/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно. Я за это любля `Vue`, что такие простые вещи так просто и делаются. Надеюсь ты сможешь разобраться с кодом.

*PS. можно запустить код прямо здесь на сайте*

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="input" type="text" @keypress.enter="add">
  <button type="button" @click="add">
    add
  </button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        input: null,
        items: ['one', 'two']
      }
    },
    methods: {
      add () {
        this.items.push(this.input);
        this.input = '';
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Dar Модераторы подправили мой ответ, теперь выглядит вообще идеально )