# Получение данных от пользователя input-form Vue

Tags: vue.js

Есть шаблон, который отображает данные в виде `<li>`. В нем есть кнопка, которая отображает впадающее окна с формой. Данные из формы изменяют объект data, за счет чего происходит ререндер.

Мой шаблон:

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(worker, index) in workers">
      <span>{{ worker.name }}</span>
      <span>{{ worker.profession }}</span>
      <span>{{ worker.age }}</span>
      <button v-on:click="showDialog()">Update info</button>
    </li>
    <form v-if="toggleDialog">
      <input id="input-name" placeholder="enter name..."/><br>
      <input id="input-profession" placeholder="enter profession..."/><br>
      <input id="input-age" placeholder="enter age..."/>
      <button v-on:click="submitChanges()">Submit changes</button>
   </form>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Сам код:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    toggleDialog: false,
    workers: [
      {
        name: 'Andrew',
        profession: 'Engineer',
        age: 22
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    showDialog() {
      this.toggleDialog = !this.toggleDialog;
    }, 
    submitChanges(index) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.workers[0].name = document.getElementById('input-name').value;
        this.workers[0].profession = document.getElementById('input-profession').value;
        this.workers[0].age = document.getElementById('input-age').value;
        this.toggleDialog = !this.toggleDialog;
    }
  }
})
```

Хотелось бы узнать, как можно организовать код, чтобы получать данные введенные пользователем без использования `DOM` или `Jq` в методе `submitChanges`?
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1wLo6p8/3/)

Comment: Можно через `v-model` Вот вам небольшой пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879338/vue-createappend-dom-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-js/879345#879345

Comment: У `Vue.js` очень хорошая документация, тем более переведенная на русский. Работа с формами: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается через [v-model](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html).

- Вместо `v-on:click="submitChanges()"` лучше использовать
  @click="submitChanges".
- [data должна быть функцией](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-data-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9)
- Для v-for надо всегда указывать атрибут key, в вашем случает будет: `:key="index"`
- В данном случает вместо `v-if="toggleDialog"` будет производительней использовать `v-show="toggleDialog"`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    toggleDialog: false,
    dialog: {
      name: null,
      profession: null,
      age: null
    },
    workers: [
      {
        name: 'Andrew',
        profession: 'Engineer',
        age: 22
      }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    showDialog () {
      this.toggleDialog = !this.toggleDialog;
    }, 
    submitChanges () {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.workers[0] = { ...this.workers[0], ...this.dialog };
      this.toggleDialog = !this.toggleDialog;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(worker, index) in workers" :key="index">
      <span>{{ worker.name }}</span>
      <span>{{ worker.profession }}</span>
      <span>{{ worker.age }}</span>
      <button @click="showDialog">Update info</button>
    </li>
    <form v-show="toggleDialog" @submit="submitChanges">
      <input v-model="dialog.name" placeholder="enter name..."/><br>
      <input v-model="dialog.profession" placeholder="enter profession..."/><br>
      <input v-model="dialog.age" placeholder="enter age..."/>
      <button>Submit changes</button>
   </form>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать ссылки. Про это можно почитать [здесь](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).

```
<input id="input-name" ref="name" placeholder="enter name..."/><br>
<input id="input-profession" ref="profession" placeholder="enter profession..."/><br>
<input id="input-age" ref="age" placeholder="enter age..."/>
```

тогда

```
this.workers[0].name = this.$refs.name.value;
this.workers[0].profession = this.$refs.profession.value;
this.workers[0].age = this.$refs.age.value;
```

Comment: Намного лучше `v-model`

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько Возможно лучше, но в вопрос был о том как получить данные с формы, а не как их туда сохранять.