# Как сюда добавить ещё одно поле?

Tags: vue.js

Как сюда добавить ещё одно поле телефона например, чтобы при клике на кнопку в список залетали и телефон и имья.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <button @click="addItem">Create</button>

        <input type="text" id="itemForm" placeholder="firstname">
        <input type="text" id="itemForm" placeholder="telephone">

        <ol>
            <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos">
                {{ todo.text }}
                <button @click="deleteFind(index)">X</button>

            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
var app4 = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        todos: [

        ]
    },
    methods: {
        addItem() {
            var input = document.getElementById('itemForm');
            app4.todos.push({ text:input.value })
        },
        deleteFind(index) {
            this.todos.splice(index, 1);
        },
        updateList(){
            Vue.set(this.todos, 0, '  ');
        }


    }
})
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение данных от пользователя input-form Vue](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879800/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-input-form-vue)

Comment: через модель или через форму

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html